# Drupal 8 don't display html tags as value of field

Tags: theming

In mytheme.theme I find the value:

```
$programmes = [];
$view = Views::getView('participating_programmes');
$view->execute();
foreach($view->result as $row){
    $nid = $row->_entity->get('nid')->getValue();
    $nid = $nid[0]['value'];
$text = $row->_entity->get('field_copy_text')->getValue();    
$programmes[$nid]['text'] = $text[0]['value'];
```

And I output it in my twig with:

```
{{ programme.text }}
```

I get the full html with all tags:

```
<p>This is the <strong>copy </strong>text for the Music subject.</p> <p>This is a <em>second </em>line with a break.</p>
```

I don't want to strip the tags. I want to display it as html output with breaks and styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change on your twig file to output HTML as:

```
{{ programme.text|raw }}
```